# Error when adding an image to an Mail - MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to send an Image, which I have added to my Project, using the MFMailComposeViewController.

I tried this in the simulator and it works fine, I can also see the Image in the Textfield, but when I'm trying to send the Mail, I get the following error on console:

> Feb 10 16:22:02 markuss-macbook-pro.speedport.ip RMC Konus[1825] : CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.

My code:

```
//Get the Image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

//Create the Mail View
MFMailComposeViewController *mailCV = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[mailCV setMailComposeDelegate:self];



[mailCV addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"exGraphic.png"];

//Show the View Controller
[self presentViewController:mailCV animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Not sure if that would help with the error you're getting, but have you considered loading the `NSData` for the image directly from the image file?

I mean getting the path for your image in application's bundle by calling

    `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"image" ofType: @"png"];`

and then loading the `NSData` using the  `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path]`? 

In your current implementation you decode the .png image first when calling `-imageNamed:` and then encode it back again using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. That seems to be an unreasonable overhead.

Comment: You say you are actually sending the email. This means you must be running the app on a real device. Are you sure that the image's name is really `image.png` and not something else like `image.PNG` or `Image.png`? Case matters on a real device. Run the code in the debugger and verify that `image` isn't `nil`.

Comment: I have checked this, the NSData object is not nil...
@Egor: Thanks for your advice about the loading of the image, I had changed this but the error still appear

Comment: Again, a semi-random suggestion which may be worth trying. Have you checked if the error still appears if you try attaching a JPEG image representation instead of PNG?

Comment: @Egor, please look to my Comment to the Answer of Ravindra. I think the problem doesn't come from the Image, as I see, I can see the Image in the Mail View. The error appears only, if I get a warning dialog in the MailComposerView

Comment: And you're certain that `image` isn't `nil`?  Not the `NSData` object, but the original `UIImage` object.

Comment: @Tim: Yes I'm sure, I can see the image in the MailBody of the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems only appears in the simulator. 
I check these code on many different devices and it still works without problems. So I would say, it is a problem of the simulator ...

Answer (score 0):

Return Value of UIImagePNGRepresentation (from apple document)-

> A data object containing the PNG data, or nil if there was a problem
>   generating the data. This function may return nil if the image has no
>   data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported
>   bitmap format.

that means check whether your image is supported for converting it into NSData with png format, because you are receiving NULL here.your error `CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.` says that it is NULL.
check by changing image . also check without using `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` because this method has many disadvantageous.

another one thing, you have converted image.png image into NSData & sending another image exGraphic.png as attachment,check it

Comment: I have checked this, the NSData object is not nil

Comment: Ok, I have checked this, I don't send any other Image with the name. But I found out one other stange thing. The error only appears, when the Subject field is empty and I get the warning, that I have added an empty subject. If I add some text to the Subject field, no error appears ...

Comment: Is this an error or a warning?  Does the app crash when this message appears?  It may be a simulator quirk with how mail is implemented on it (it is not the real Mail app).  Try leaving out the attachment code and see if the error still occurs when you leave out the subject.

Comment: @Tim: The App doesn't crash, I get only the message, which I posted in my question.

If I leave the attachment code, the error doesn't appear ...

Comment: And do you get this message on the simulator?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. 
I see the message, when I use the simulator, on the console from xCode .