# CGImageCreate: invalid image size 0 x 0, when opening control center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm working on a tabbed application with a custom UINavigationBar. Whenever I open the control center in the iOS Simulator, the command line in Xcode keeps giving me the following error:

**CGImageCreate: invalid image size 0 x 0.**

It occurs in every ViewController, even in empty ones.

Could this has to do something with a custom UINavigationBar or TabBar?

This is the code which is in my appdelegate.m file which I use for the tab bar

```
    DMFirstViewController *firstViewController = [[DMFirstViewController alloc] init];
    DMSecViewController *secondViewController = [[DMSecViewController alloc] init];
    DMThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[DMThirdViewController alloc] init];
    DMFourthViewController *fourthViewController = [[DMFourthViewController alloc] init];

    tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController, fourthViewController, nil];

    tabController.viewControllers = controllers;


    UIImage *unselectedTabFirst = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first_line.png"];
    UIImage *selectedTabFirst = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first_active.png"];

    UIImage *unselectedTabSec = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second_line.png"];
    UIImage *selectedTabSec = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second_active.png"];

    UIImage *unselectedTabThird = [UIImage imageNamed:@"third_line.png"];
    UIImage *selectedTabThird = [UIImage imageNamed:@"third_active.png"];

    UIImage *unselectedTabFourth = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fourth_line.png"];
    UIImage *selectedTabFourth = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fourth_active.png"];


    unselectedTabFirst = [unselectedTabFirst imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    selectedTabFirst = [selectedTabFirst imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    unselectedTabSec = [unselectedTabSec imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    selectedTabSec = [selectedTabSec imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    unselectedTabThird = [unselectedTabThird imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    selectedTabThird = [selectedTabThird imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    unselectedTabFourth = [unselectedTabFourth imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    selectedTabFourth = [selectedTabFourth imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];



    firstViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"first" image:unselectedTabFirst selectedImage:selectedTabFirst];

    secondViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"second" image:unselectedTabSec selectedImage:selectedTabSec];

    thirdViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"third" image:unselectedTabThird selectedImage:selectedTabThird];

    fourthViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"fourth" image:unselectedTabFourth selectedImage:selectedTabFourth];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799908/error-when-adding-an-image-to-an-mail-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Yes, it does. You should post your Custom navigation to get rid of errors...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the link shows from Retro, this only happens in the iOS simulator. Running the app on a developer device won't create this error.

Problem solved!

Comment: I see that happen on iPad 2 simulator, running on iPad Air 2 simulator is OK